# Pass DateTime arguments with JNI c++

Tags: java, c++, datetime, java-native-interface

I am using JNI and I need to pass DateTime as an argument to a method. What format should I use?

Here is an example of my code:

```
int number = 10;
initial = env->GetMethodID(Simulator,"initialize", "(Ljava/util/Date;Ljava/util/Date;I)V");
if (env->ExceptionCheck()){
  cout << "Fail:";
}
env->CallVoidMethod(Simulation,initial,"2014/05/21T00:00:00","2014/05/21T23:59:59",number);
```

I need to pass these Dates as Ljava/util/Date arguments and not as strings because I can't change the java code that JNI calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to create the two `java.util.Date` objects first. Like this:

```
int number = 10;
jmethodID initial = env->GetMethodID(Simulator,"initialize", "(Ljava/util/Date;Ljava/util/Date;I)V");
if (env->ExceptionCheck()){
  cout << "Fail:";
}
jclass dateType = env->FindClass("Ljava/util/Date;");
if(dateType == nullptr){
  cout << "Fail:";
}
jmethodID dateTypeConstructor= env->GetMethodID(dateType, "<init>", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
if(constructor == nullptr){
  cout << "Fail:";
}
jstring constructorString1 = env->NewStringUTF("2014/05/21T00:00:00");
jobject dateObject1 = env->NewObject(dateType , dateTypeConstructor, constructorString1);
if(dateObject1  == nullptr)
  cout << "Fail:";
}
jstring constructorString2 = env->NewStringUTF("2014/05/21T23:59:59");
jobject dateObject2 = env->NewObject(dateType , dateTypeConstructor, constructorString2);
if(dateObject2  == nullptr)
  cout << "Fail:";
}
env->CallVoidMethod(Simulation, initial, dateObject1, dateObject2, number);
```

The constructor `Date(String s)` is [deprecated since JDK 1.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), but the principle is the same if you have to use a [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) or you can just write a static method in Java which will return a `java.util.Date` Object for the String that you pass to it.

Comment: i will check this now!I feel you have to change constructor --> dateTypeConstructor inside `NewObject`

Comment: You're right - I've changed it, thanks! But be aware, that it probably won't just work, because the `java.util.Date` constructor with a String as Parameter seems deprecated to me.

Comment: @EJP Oh, ok I see - I thought it would be gone in newer JDKs already. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: ok, then seems right but it return NULL when trying to create the `jobject dateObject1` i have already cheched and jclass,jmethodID and jstring is ok...

Comment: Have you tried to use `if (env->ExceptionOccurred()) { env->ExceptionDescribe(); }` after calling `NewObject()` to see if & what Kind of Exception happened?

Comment: I finally did it with public Date(int year,int month,int date,int hrs,int min, int sec). But i am not sure if that creates the requested foramt e.g 2014/05/21T00:00:00

Comment: I am getting the long value of `getTime()` in order to check the Date in a Java code after but is giviing me dates around 1970.